# No TLS support in VLC 2.1.5 (win64)?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, vlc, libvlc, win64

Any tries to stream media from https fails with `TLS plugin not available` error (see message log [here](http://pastebin.com/b30jnwuj/))

Whereas, trying the same stream using Win32 VLC version (also 2.1.5) succeeds (see message log [here](http://pastebin.com/HB7gey8M).

Is there a reason why x64 VLC version does not support encrypted connections?

---

Windows 8.1, VLC 2.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to a bug. In VLC 3.0.0, the latest nightly build, there appears to be no problems streaming videos that require TLS. You can find it here if interested: http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/win64/vlc-3.0.0-20150203-0441/

Note that because it's an unstable build there may be other issues.